# make child div wider than parent

Tags: html, css

I know this is maybe a duplicate question, but I have already searching and trying all answer here. and there is no solution for my problem :(

My Question :
https://jsbin.com/wujiliqehi/1/edit?html,css,output

how to make *materikonten* wider than *card* likes secondary pic ?

Solution :

```
div#materi-konten{width: auto;margin: 0 -20px; !important;} 
.card{overflow: visible !important;}
```

another solution for responsive layout

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px){
    div#materi-konten{width: auto;margin: 0 -20px; !important;} 
    .card{overflow: visible !important;}}
```

sorry for my bad english &
thanks for everyone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm so sorry,, because I'm working with another css library. this will takes sometimes :(

Comment: You don't really need a library to do this, just simply start working from a blank page and start from there. This sounds simple enough to try on its own and add to the final CSS later.

Comment: @somethinghere thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no `overflow:hidden` on the parent div (*card*), then you could set `position:relative`, set the `top` and `left` properties to place the child in the correct position, then use `width` and `height` to make it the right size. This would be VERY difficult to do responsively - you would be stuck with fixed size boxes I think.

Without code examples of what you have tried, I cannot be of more help.

Comment: I'm surprised you understood the question :)

Comment: I speak two languages - English and Bad English ;)

Comment: really, really sorry for my BAD english. anyway thanks o__o

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it bigger in the CSS, either with pixels or percentage:

```
.materi-konten {

  width: 110%;
  left: -5%;

}

.card {

  overflow: visible; /* make sure we can see the child if it is bigger */

}
```

Comment: nice question too, thanks